# Limit feeds returned

Tags: jquery, rss, feed

I'm trying to set a limit on the number of RSS feeds returned using the script below. In an ideal world I would like to show the most recent 5 feeds but I'm unsure how to achieve this. I *think* I need to use:

```
var limit = 5
```

...somewhere (and probably along with some other code), but I am not getting anywhere. The code is:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://forumURL",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function (xml) {
      $(xml).find("entry").each(function () {
         $("#forum").append("<li><a href='" + 
         $(this).find("link").attr("href") + "'>" + 
         $(this).find("title").text() + "</a></li>");
      });
    }
});
```

Any idea how I can only show 5 results from the feed? Thanks in advance for any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Update your success function to include a counter:

```
success: function(xml) {
    var counter = 0;
    $(xml).find("entry").each(function() {
        if (counter < 5) $("#forum").append("<li><a href='" + $(this).find("link").attr("href") + "'>" + $(this).find("title").text() + "</a></li>");
        counter++;
    });
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [slice](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/slice) function to get the first `limit` results:

```
$(xml).find("entry").slice(0, limit).each(function () { /*..*/ });
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Tried and tested and working fine (I think). Used:

Comment: $(xml).find("entry").slice(-5).each(function () { /*..*/ }); to show only 5 results and seems to be working. Thanks.